# How to cluster similar lists together?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I’m looking for an algorithm that’s able to group lists of strings who have almost the same content.

This is an example of lists. Totally there are 5 different words.

```
A = ['first', 'second', 'third']
B = ['first', 'forth']
C = ['second', 'third']
D = ['first', 'third']
E = ['first', 'fifth']
F = ['fourth', 'fifth']
```

You can see that A, C and D have a lot in common and also B, E and F.

I thought about a clustering algorithmn thats able to give almost the same list a same cluster.

I want to two clusters making sure one word is at least at one cluster.

In this example list A, C and D should have cluster 1

and B, E and F cluster 2.

Is there an algorithm (or machine learning) in Python that can be used for this type of problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a good use case for a [Latent Dirichlet allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) model.

---

A `LDA` is a an unsupervised model that finds similar groups among a set of observations, which you can then use to assign a *Topic* to each of them.

Here's how you could go about this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import lda
```

Fit a [`CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) to obtain a matrix of token counts from the list of strings:

```
l = [' '.join(i) for i in [A,B,C,D,E,F]]
vec = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1))

X = vec.fit_transform(l)
```

Use [`lda`](https://pypi.org/project/lda/) and fit a model on the result from the `CountVectorizer` (there are also other modules with a `lda` model implementation, such as in [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html))

```
model = lda.LDA(n_topics=2, random_state=1)
model.fit(X)
```

And assign a group number the the `2` created topics:

```
doc_topic = model.doc_topic_

for i in range(len(l)):
    print(f'Cluster {i}: Topic ', doc_topic[i].argmax())

Cluster 0: Topic  1 # -> A
Cluster 1: Topic  0
Cluster 2: Topic  1 # -> C
Cluster 3: Topic  1 # -> D
Cluster 4: Topic  0
Cluster 5: Topic  0
```